# me marca el error en los dos puntos

Tags: python

Estaba escribiendo un codigo simple y al ejecutarlo me da un error y reviso todo y me marca que son los dos puntos,aqui les dejo el codigo.

```
locations = {
(35.12312, 14.0000):"Tokyo"
(35.12312, 19.0000):"new york"
}


y me da el siguiente error
```

```
File "C:\Users\David y Sebas\Desktop\python-course\tuples.py", line 20
(35.12312, 19.0000):"new york"
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Tienes que dar un valor, no puedes dejar una llave sin su valor.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error se debe a que no pusiste comas entre los elementos de tu diccionario.

Si haces una lista, tupla, diccionario, set, etc, aunque abarquen varias lineas, siempre tiene que haber una coma entre un valor y otro.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de una lista que abarca varias lineas de código:

```
["hola",
 "stack",
 "overflow"]
```

Como notarás, uso la coma para separar cada item de la lista.

Para que tu código funcione, simplemente tienes que aplicar este mismo principio a tu diccionario:

```
locations = {
(35.12312, 14.0000):"Tokyo",
(35.12312, 19.0000):"new york"
}
```